# Prisma deploy gives error GraphQL Tutorial

Tags: docker, constructor, schema, graphql, prisma

I am currently following a [GraphQL Tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/0-introduction/) and am on the "Add a Database" section explaining how to set up Prisma with GraphQL.

I finished adding the information in the prisma.yml file, installed prisma, ran prisma deploy and followed the steps, but every time I run prisma info, prisma token, or prisma deploy again, I keep getting the same error:

`TypeError: url_1.URL is not a constructor`

I have been trying to look up solutions to the error. I tried updating node and npm, downloading docker but nothing seems to be making any difference.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share what OS you're running on?

Comment: Oh right, sorry about that. Mac OS, the version with the touch bar.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into [this issue](https://github.com/prismagraphql/prisma/issues/2308).

Basically, this is a known issue with node 6.x.

Please update the node version to fix this issue and track the progress of above issue in case you want to continue to use node 6.x.